# getFullYear not working when using the loop counter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops

I'm sure there is a good reason for this, but doesn't seem to come to my head.
I'm working with Angular and I'm using the function getFullYear() inside a "for" loop that goes through an array of objects. When I use e.g. booked[i].getFullYear(), (being i the counter in the "for" definition) it says booked[i].getFullYear is not a function, but if I say booked[0].getFullYear - just replacing the counter by a number (or a var with a number created inside the loop)- it works.

e.g.

```
 for (gig in $scope.booked ){   
            var i =0; //new var to use as a counter
            $scope.booked[gig].visualDate={
                year: $scope.booked[i].when.getFullYear(), //works
                //year: $scope.booked[gig].when.getFullYear() //does not work
            };
            //i++; I can't use it as a counter
    };
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must show more code than that... or else we won't see the root of the error.

How is $scope.booked initialized and how is it collecting. Is it an object with index number keys or an array with number keys?

Comment: Sounds like you might have some non-integer value in the `$scope.booked` , can you do a `console.log(gig);` inside the for-loop to verify that they are all valid integer, so it's not trying to call $scope.booked[''] or something else invalid. *(As an alternative, try doing a classic numeric for-loop using `$scope.booked.length` and see if the error disappears.)*

Answer (score -2):

You must show more code than that... or else we won't see the **root of the error**.

How is **$scope.booked** initialized and how is it collecting. Is it an object with index number keys or an array with number keys?

Comment: question to OP should be added as a comment?

Comment: o ok I thought I couldn't do that yet.